# Is there a limit in the number of recipient with swaks?

Tags: email

The maximum number of recipient for gmail is 500.

**Is there any limit in the number of recipient using `swaks`?**

```
swaks -t recipient1@mail.com -t recipient2@mail.com -t recipient3@mail.com [...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gmail limit (*n* recipients per mail, *m* mails/day) is enforced on the SMTP server to prevent an user from spamming; it is not a hard limit due to the specific command Google uses to send mail. As such, using a command line tool to connect to Gmail SMTP server won't change this limit.

Note that passing 500 recipients to `swaks` (or to any other command) might fail due to the very long list of arguments, not because there's a limit in the number of recipients (which can easily be bypassed by sending 10 mails with 50 recipients each).